# Temporary tables killing performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written this query and because I used temporary tables (for the first time), it massively killed the performance of the query.

This is the query. Can you spot a massive mistake that I am making?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME 
SET @StartDate = '20160720';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME 
SET @EndDate = '20160729 23:59:59';

Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [1stchargeableweights], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]
 Into #1schargslack

                                    FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                       inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                       --INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                                                                                                  --AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                  AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                  AND c.[Service Type] = 'F'
                                                                                                  AND ts.SlackNoSlack = 'slack' 
                                                                                                  or ts.slacknoslack like 'slack - tripped%'
                                                                                                  GROUP by mm.MovementRef 
Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [1stchargeableweightns], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]
 Into #1chargns


                                    FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                       inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                       --INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                                                                                                  --AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                  AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                  AND c.[Service Type] = 'F'
                                                                                                  and ts.SlackNoSlack like 'no slack%'
                                                                                                  GROUP BY mm.MovementRef
Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [2ndchargeableweights], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]
 Into #2chargs

                                    FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                        inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                       inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                      -- INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                                                                                                              -- AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                               AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                               AND c.[Service Type] = 'C'
                                                                                                               AND ts.SlackNoSlack = 'slack' 
                                                                                                               or ts.slacknoslack like 'slack - tripped%'
                                                                                                               GROUP BY mm.MovementRef                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [2ndchargeableweightns], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]
 Into #2chargns

                                    FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                        inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                       inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                      -- INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                                                                                                               -- AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                                AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                                AND c.[Service Type] = 'C'
                                                                                                                and ts.SlackNoSlack like 'no slack%'
                                                                                                                group by mm.MovementRef 
Select  
SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS [2ndchargeableweightlate], 
mm.MovementRef [movementref], 
MAX (ts.systemstamp) [lastdate]
 Into #2charglate

                                    FROM      dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       INNER JOIN dbo.tsAdditionalColInfo ts on ts.[ConsignmentReference]= wc.ConsignmentReference
                                                       inner join dbo.movConLink m on m.ConsignmentReference = c.[Consignment Reference]
                                                       inner join dbo.movMovement mm on mm.MovementID = m.MovementID
                                                      -- INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                                                                                                              --  AND wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
                                                                                                                AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
                                                                                                                AND c.[Service Type] = 'C'                                                                                
                                                                                                                and ts.SlackNoSlack like '%late%'
                                                                                                                group by mm.movementref
    SELECT --wh.WhsHeaderID,
              mu.Number AS Unit,
        m.MovementRef AS Reference,
        wh.ArrDepDate AS [Departure Date],
        wh.LastScannedTime AS [Last Scan],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), wh.ArrDepDate, 108) AS [Scheduled Departure (h)],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), wh.LastScannedTime, 108) AS [Last Scan (h)],                
        CASE
            WHEN
            (
                m.DestinationPoint = 'SF' 
                AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, wh.ArrDepDate, wh.LastScannedTime) > 180
            )
            OR (m.DestinationPoint <> 'SF'  AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, wh.ArrDepDate, wh.LastScannedTime) > 20) THEN
                'Late'
            ELSE
                'On Time'
        END AS Status,
        CAST(ch.ChargeableWt + ISNULL(LO.LeftOffWt, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Planned Chargeable Wt],
        Cast (isnull ([1stchargeableweights], 0) as decimal (18, 2)) as [1st Dep Left off Chargeable Wt With Slack],
        Cast (isnull ([1stchargeableweightns], 0) as decimal (18, 2)) as [1st Dep Left off Chargeable Wt No Slack],
        Cast (isnull ([2ndchargeableweights], 0) as decimal (18, 2)) as [2nd Dep Left off Chargeable Wt With Slack],
        Cast (isnull ([2ndchargeableweightns], 0) as decimal (18, 2)) as [2nd Dep Left off Chargeable Wt No Slack],
        Cast (isnull ([2ndchargeableweightlate], 0) as decimal (18, 2)) as [2nd Dep Left off Chargeable Wt Late],
        CAST(ch.ChargeableWt AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Actual Chargeable Wt],

        CASE
            WHEN m.DestinationPoint IN ( 'AT', 'FR', 'PL', 'NL', 'BE', 'ES', 'IT', 'CH', 'CZ', 'TU', 'MT', 'DE' ) THEN
                22000
            ELSE
                20000
        END AS Target,
        CASE
            WHEN m.DestinationPoint IN ( 'AT', 'FR', 'PL', 'NL', 'BE', 'ES', 'IT', 'CH', 'CZ', 'TU', 'MT', 'DE' ) THEN
                CAST(ch.ChargeableWt - 22000 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
            ELSE
                CAST(ch.ChargeableWt - 20000 AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
        END AS Variance
        --ISNULL(
        --          STUFF(
        --                                   (
        --                                          SELECT ', ' + COALESCE(R.Region, 'Region not found') + ': ' + SUBSTRING(cnor.PostCode,1,CHARINDEX(   ' ',cnor.PostCode + ' ') - 1) + 
        --                                                                   ' (' + COALESCE(DC.Description, 'NA') + ')' 
        --                                          FROM dbo.whsConsignment wc
        --                                                 INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference AND c.Cancelled = 0
        --                                                 INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress cnor ON cnor.AddressID = c.Consignor
        --                                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.disConsignment AS DC ON DC.ConsignmentRef = wc.ConsignmentReference AND DC.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
        --                                                 LEFT JOIN dbo.lstPostcode P ON P.Postcode = cnor.PostcodePrefix
        --                                                 LEFT JOIN dbo.lstPostcodeRegion R ON R.RegionID = P.RegionID
        --                                          WHERE wc.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID AND wc.StatusCode = 'NL'
        --                                          FOR XML PATH('')
        --                                        ),
        --                   1,1,''
        --               )
        --     ,'') AS [Postcodes & Discrepancies]       
    FROM dbo.movMovement m
    inner join #1schargslack on #1schargslack.movementref = m.MovementRef
    inner join #1chargns on #1chargns.movementref = m.MovementRef
    inner join #2chargs on #2chargs.movementref = m.MovementRef
    inner join #2chargns on #2chargns.MovementRef = m.MovementRef
    inner join #2charglate on #2charglate.movementref = m.MovementRef
        INNER JOIN dbo.movUnit mu ON mu.UnitID = m.TrailerID
        INNER JOIN dbo.whsHeader wh ON wh.RunMovID = m.MovementID AND wh.LocalDepotCode = 'NOT' AND wh.WhsJobType = 'CL' AND wh.WhsJobStatus = 'COMP'
        LEFT JOIN dbo.whsHeaderComments whc ON whc.ID = wh.WhsHeaderID
        INNER JOIN (
                                         SELECT MovementID,
                                                SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS ChargeableWt
                                         FROM dbo.movConLink mc 
                                                 INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = mc.ConsignmentReference AND c.Cancelled = 0
                                         GROUP BY mc.MovementID
                                  ) ch ON ch.MovementID = m.MovementID
        LEFT JOIN (
                                  SELECT wc.whsHeaderID,
                                         SUM(c.[Chargeable Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
                                  FROM dbo.whsConsignment wc
                                         INNER JOIN dbo.cgtConsignment c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference AND c.Cancelled = 0
                                         INNER JOIN dbo.genAddress cnor ON cnor.AddressID = c.Consignor
                                  WHERE StatusCode IN ( 'NL' )
                                  GROUP BY wc.whsHeaderID
                              ) LO ON LO.whsHeaderID = wh.WhsHeaderID
    WHERE wh.ArrDepDate
    BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    ORDER BY m.MovementRef;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work this way.  You can't dump hundreds of line of SQL code and expect anyone to sift through it.  _Edit_ your question and maybe show us _one_ query which is having problems with temporary tables.

Comment: Not related to your question, but i don't see this as a good setting if you are new to SQL Server (and not only) `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

Comment: Hi Horia, can you please expand on that? why is SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; unsuitable? Thank you!

Comment: To add on to what Tim already said, also format your queries so that they can be read easily. The way they are formatted now, you have to scroll to the right to get any sense of the query(ies).

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating a temp table and then only calling from it once, you can look at using CTE's. It will save a alot of time where SQL Server is populating the tables.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you dbajtr! I will look into using CTE's then :)

Comment: No worries- also if your using temp tables remember to drop them at the end of your query